# How to show hide elements using spring security

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have a button which i want to show in login page.

So when the user is logged in i want to hide this button. I think

```
<sec:authorize access="isAuthenticated()">
```

is useful for this so i included something like following in my jsp

```
<sec:authorize access="not isAuthenticated()">
            <div class="pull-right">
```

But is not visible in the login page as well as after logged in.

What can be the problem.

```
<http pattern="/foobar/static-wro4j/**" security="none"/>
<http pattern="/foobar/static/**" security="none"/>
<http pattern="/foobar/login*" security="none"/>
<http pattern="/foobar/syndic/**" security="none"/>
<http pattern="/foobar/register/**" security="none"/>
<http pattern="/foobar/lostpassword/**" security="none"/>

<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" create-session="ifRequired">
    <remember-me key="foobarRememberKey" token-validity-seconds="2592000"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/foobar/presentation" access="permitAll()"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/foobar/tos" access="permitAll()"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/foobar/license" access="permitAll()"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/foobar/404-error" access="permitAll()"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/foobar/500-error" access="permitAll()"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/foobar/rest/users" method="POST" access="permitAll()"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/metrics/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()"/>

    <form-login
            login-processing-url="/foobar/authentication"
            login-page="/foobar/login"
            authentication-failure-url="/foobar/login?action=loginFailure"
            default-target-url="/foobar/"
            authentication-success-handler-ref="foobarAuthenticationSuccessHandler"/>
    <http-basic/>
    <logout logout-url="/foobar/logout"
            logout-success-url="/foobar/login"/>

    <openid-login authentication-failure-url="/foobar/login?action=loginFailure"
                  user-service-ref="openIdAutoRegisteringUserDetailsService">
        <!-- Only Google Apps is supported -->
        <attribute-exchange identifier-match="https://www.google.com/.*">
            <openid-attribute name="email" type="http://axschema.org/contact/email" required="true" count="1"/>
            <openid-attribute name="firstname" type="http://axschema.org/namePerson/first" required="true"/>
            <openid-attribute name="lastname" type="http://axschema.org/namePerson/last" required="true"/>
        </attribute-exchange>
    </openid-login>
</http>
```

Comment: If you still have issues post your config.

Comment: still access="isAnonymous() not working...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure you have included the Spring Security Tag Library in the JSP:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="sec" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" %>
```

In your security configuration include:

```
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler"/>
```

Then use the `authorize` tag:

```
<sec:authorize access="isAuthenticated()">
   <!-- Content for Authenticated users -->  
</sec:authorize>

<sec:authorize access="isAnonymous()">
   <!-- Content for Unauthenticated users -->  
</sec:authorize>
```

Comment: You do not need declare explicitly  `DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler` if you use `<http>` tag in your conf.