# Authority actions in Spring Security

Tags: java, javascript, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, spring-security

In Spring Security is possible to control actions?

For example: The url /coca-cola everyone has access to it (ROLE_USUARIO, ROLE_EMPRESA).

But will have 1 button to edit or delete any data in the page /coca-cola.

I need this button to be displayed only for the company /coca-cola, other companies who access this page or other users who access it can not see this button. This is possible in Spring Security? Or I have to create a logic to this?

Comment: yes possible, what you tried?

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18149196/how-to-show-hide-elements-using-spring-security

Comment: That's not my question. 
I need to display a button only when ROLE_ESTABELECIMENTO and the page is my. @Jay

Comment: @Rembo I tried is: `<a href="#!/edit/{{newsEntry.id}}" class="btn btn-xs btn-default" ng-show="hasRole('ROLE_EMPRESA') && isMyPage()">Edit</a>` The ROLE works perfectly. Now I need to check if I am the owner of that page.

Answer (score 0):

In your page (eg jsp), add the code like below. If the current user has the role 'ROLE_ESTABELECIMENTO', then that block of code would become visible where you can put your button to display it. Else it would be hidden. Is this what you need ?

```
        <%@ taglib prefix="security" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" %>


        <security:authorize access="hasRole('ROLE_ESTABELECIMENTO')">
            Code to display your button
        </security:authorize>
```

You might need to add the library 'spring-security-taglibs', if you use maven as below

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```